# How to create a new column based on a column made from a shift

Tags: python, pandas

I'm adding a new column to my dataframe based on the future values of the stock to see if the prices increases or decreases, I do it the following way:

```
df['future'] = df['adjclose'].shift(-1)
df.dropna(subset=['future'], how='all', inplace=True)
df['rising'] = df.apply(lambda x : 'True' if x['future'] >= x['adjclose'] else 'False', axis=1)
```

This ends up with this dataframe:

```
          open        high         low       close    adjclose    volume        date   upperband  middleband   lowerband      future  rising
0   267.279999  275.579987  266.130005  273.600006  273.600006  39712000  2022-04-04  288.215660  275.407996  262.600331  259.309998   False
1   272.540009  273.190002  258.200012  259.309998  259.309998  43661500  2022-04-05  282.329293  269.957996  257.586699  244.070007   False
2   249.339996  253.000000  240.029999  244.070007  244.070007  70383300  2022-04-06  285.259714  263.391998  241.524283  242.080002   False
3   244.410004  247.220001  234.779999  242.080002  242.080002  55799200  2022-04-07  282.100807  257.236002  232.371197  231.190002   False
4   239.169998  239.229996  230.619995  231.190002  231.190002  52409100  2022-04-08  279.651774  250.050003  220.448232  219.169998   False
```

As you can see in some cases ['future'] is higher than ['adjclose'] and it makes the new column False when it should be True.

I reach a point where i found that the problem is with the data shift since I tested with other columns and it works perfectly, the only one that is giving me trouble is the 'future' one.

```
df['future'] = df['adjclose'].shift(-1)
```

But I don't know how to fix it exactly

Comment: *in some cases ['future'] is higher than ['adjclose']* For the given sample, future is never higher than adjclose, no?

Comment: In the first row future is 259.309998 and adjclose is 273.600006. It should be true in theory

Comment: `259 >= 273 = False`...??

Answer (score 0):

you are just trying to do that right ?

```
x['rising']=0
x['rising'] = np.where(x['future'] >= x['adjclose'],True,False)
```

Comment: yes, I tried that way too. It has to be with the shift. If I use any other column than 'future' for the operation the result is as expected